# Does SO not welcome text-book styled questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357914/xpath-to-select-top-level-elements-not-on-the-path-to-a-given-element) with a bit of abstraction in a way most computer science questions are presented in text-books and was graced with a comment, two down-votes and a close request for apparently unclear question.

I've since added the context that prompted the question, but I was shocked by the hostility against the question. Does SO not like this kind of text-book/theoretical styled questions?

I understand for many cases, such question have a better alterntive solution, so some context would be helpful, but IMHO some questions can benefit from a more generic/abstract discussion.

For example, I would never expect a question like "How to sort a list of elements based on abstract comparator C" to be a bad programming question, but under the current climate, the question would be down-voted to hell with people asking why you would want to sort and what is C...

(In other words, maybe my confusion is about whether SO is trying to be a Q&A site for specific questions or a knowledge base.)

Comment: I don't think the problem here is about "text-book style". Your question was not clear (I don't understand why you want `d` in the output but not `b`, for instance, even after reading your clarification). It is perfectly legitimate for users to ask about your actual requirements in comments in this situation (mostly to avoid answering the "X" part of an X-Y problem). Your reacting poorly to these comments (e.g. *your behaviour is very arrogant and community-unfriendly*, *I have a very legitimate business case*, *please don't incite me to break the law*) did not help matters at all I'm afraid.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Your first point is interesting. I posed the question this way in an attempt to make it less confusing, but obviously failed. Unfortunately, some questions are hard to explain, some maybe not even possible without exact mathematical language. I've given both prose and examples in the question, but giving an exact description would literally require the code that answers the question. // As for my reaction, I was in a bad mood after being stuck on this for almost a whole day. I didn't like the tone of the comment, but my comment didn't help either I guess.

Comment: I honestly do not know how my efforts to help you could be interpreted as "shocking hostility", which is a gross misrepresentation of my comment (you know that, I hope). Downvotes, closing and comments are there to ensure questions can be answered (from the asker's perspective) and are relevant (from the community's perspective) - do not take them personally. And please try to be nice to the poor souls that solve your problems, even if you are having a bad day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does SO not like text-book/theoretical styled questions?

We do.

> [such] question[s] would be down-voted to hell with people asking "why you would want to sort" and "what is C"

Ha-ha. Nope.

The people commenting "why" don't have to be the ones downvoting. To me, your [first revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32357914/1) reads like a homework dump, without any effort shown by you. If I would've come across it, I'd have downvoted it purely based on that.

Comment: Okay, this is something I have not thought of before but I understand the reasoning.